# Diffulties in identifying web page element in salesforce application

Tags: java, selenium

Currently working on the automation of salesforce application.
I need a quick help to check the below code, i am unable to identify the element using java container. here is the HTML source for the page.

```
<div class="pbBody">
<span id="j_id0:j_id1:j_id5:matrixGrid">
<div id="j_id0:j_id1:j_id5:j_id7">
<div class="pbSubsection">
<table class="detailList" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
<tbody>
<tr>
<tr>
<th class="labelCol vfLabelColTextWrap last " scope="row">
<td class="dataCol last ">EUR</td>
<th class="labelCol vfLabelColTextWrap last " scope="row">
<td class="dataCol last ">
<span id="j_id0:j_id1:j_id5:j_id7:j_id11:theDrPriceMatrix">Germany</span>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

JAVA Container is written here to identify element in  tag

```
WebElement w5=driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("table.detailList"));
    System.out.println(w5);

WebElement w6=w5.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/form/span/div/div/div/div/div[1]/span/div/div/table/tbody/tr[2]"));

WebElement w7=w6.findElement(By.cssSelector("td.dataCol"));

List<WebElement> l3=w7.findElements(By.tagName("span"));
for (int i = 0; i <l3.size();i++) 
{
System.out.println(l3.get(i).getText());                                    
}
l3.get(0).getText();
```

actually the issue is I am not able to write anything for  in the container

Comment: Do you want to locate span element??

Comment: yes, i want to verify the text "Germany" on the page